# Solution of linear differential operator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, mathematical-physics, differential-operators, homogeneous-equation

The linear differential operator

$$L=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+2x{\frac{d}{dx}}+6 $$

is given, and then a differential equation $$Lf_1(x)=0$$ is given, where $$f_1(x)=e^{-x^2}g(x) $$ and it is assumed that $$g(x)=a+bx+x^2 $$ .I was wondering what I need to do in order to find one solution to the differential equation and a second solution $$f_2(x)$$ of L?

Comment: Plug in the proposed $f_1(x)$ into the differential equation.

Comment: By substituting the proposed $f_1(x)$ into the DE, you'll find $a,b$ such that $f_1(x)$ is a solution. This gives you one solution. You can then use this first solution to find the second via the reduction of order method: http://sites.science.oregonstate.edu/math/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/ode/second/so_redord/so_redord.html

Comment: I'm still having trouble figuring it out. I get why $f_1(x)$  has to be plugged into the DE and it's given that g(x) vanishes when $x=-Sqrt(1/2)$ , but I'm just uncertain as to how I should proceed. Would I find the first and second derivatives? How does the linear differential operator come into play? @Semiclassical

Comment: You're misinterpreting: If it's a solution, then the differential operator must send it to zero _for all values of $x$_. So it's not a choice of $x$ that matters but of $a,b$. (Compare: If $(x-1)(x-2)=x^2+ax+b$ for all $x$, then that requires $a=-3,b=2$.)